# Login User if values exist in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

Hey guys i am having a form in which user registers and then log's in. The data from the registration username and password are stored in a hashmap like this:

```
if (usersMap.containsKey("username")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginForm.this, "User already exists !", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
} else {
    usersMap.put("username", registerUser.getText());
    usersMap.put("userpassword", registerPassword.getPassword());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginForm.this, "Registration Successful !!", "SUCCESS", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}
```

I also check for duplicate entries in the username and it works fine

The problemm occurs when i am trying to log the user in.

Here is my login code:

```
private void clickEventRightPanel() {
        loginBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                unameLog = loginUser.getText();
                logPass = loginPassword.getPassword();

                if (usersMap.values().contains(loginUser.getText()) && usersMap.values().contains(loginPassword.getPassword())) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginForm.this, "Login sucessfull !!", "SUCCESS", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginForm.this, "User does not exist ! Try again !", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

Any ideas about what possibly could go wrong in here??

Comment: Would you like to share what the problem is?

Comment: It goes to the else statement which is User does not exist

Comment: You're **completely** misusing hashmaps.  You need a map of username to hashed password.

Comment: I wonder how many users this map can store ...

Comment: Rethink your logic. The username and password can exist anywhere in the hashmap and the login will be successful. This means I can log in with someone else's password. Also as @SLaks mentioned, a hashmap is a bad idea for this.

Comment: @mdnghtblue Not really, because this map can store only one user. But the remark generally is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using or checking the map correctly. First, you need to map the username to the password:

```
usersMap.put(registerUser.getText(), registerPassword.getPassword());
```

Now whenever you have a login attempt, you try to find the username in the map, if a user is found, you compare the stored password with the login password:

```
if (usersMap.containsKey(loginUser.getText())) {
    String storedPassword = usersMap.get(loginUser.getText());
    if (storedPassword.equals(loginPassword.getPassword())) {
        // valid login
    } else {
        // invalid login
    }
} else {
    // invalid login
}
```

Comment: Well it gives me an error because what you are trying to save as storedPassword returns an Object and asks cast to String.

Comment: @Eleni Change you map from `Map` to `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: yes but the value i get from password field is not a string is a char[]

Comment: @Eleni `String pw = new String(loginPassword.getPassword())`. Or use `Map<String, char[]>`. The first code will store the password in the memory and this can be easily read by other tools.

Answer (score 0):

Since your HashMap stores the username and password as values, youll want to compare the entered values to the keys "username" and "password" corresponding values.

```
if(usersMap.containsKey("username") && userMap.containsKey("password"){
   //There is a mapping for username and password.
   if(usersMap.get("username").equals(unameLog)
    && usersMap.get("password").equals(logPass)){
        //login successful
   }
   else
      //Login failed, but mapping exists.
}else
   //No mapping for username or password.
```

Since usersMap.get("username") will return the username.

Comment: Except that in the OP's Hashmap, the password is not stored with the username as the key.

Comment: `Since your HashMap has username as the key, and password as the value` ... you should read his code again :).

Comment: it does not work like this...still goes to the else statement

Comment: well the fact is that there might be something wrong with the password...because if i use usersMap.get("username).equals(unameLog) works just fine but when i add password it fails

Answer (score -1):

Your code to check if the user exists checks the keys of the map (`usersMap.containsKey`) but the later code checks the values (`usersMap.values().contains(loginUser)`)

Comment: I tried both ways and it doesn't work...How am i supposed to check??

Comment: His key in map is "username"!!! and he is storing username as value in map. incorrect ans in this scenario.